# How to horizontal align texts and image in my case

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to keep my texts next to an image on the same horizontal level

I have something like

```
<div>
    <img src='test.png'/>
    <a href='#'>This is the test here</a>
</div>
```

it shows

```
 -----
|     |     This is the test
|     |
 -----

here

 -----
|     |     This is the test
|     |     here
 -----
```

How do i fix this? thanks!

Comment: ^^ Do you have a width set for the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
}
div img{
    float:left;
}

div a{
    float:left;
}
```